# Is it a good idea to make my MEF parts lifetime Shared on this case?

Tags: c#, iis, repository-pattern, mef, csla

I've used CSLA as a part of my Web Solution's Architecture and, in order to be able to manage repository pattern, the IoC container for my DataAccess Layer works with MEF (By using CSLA-Contrib). It is known that the first load of the MEF Catalog takes a while deppending on how huge are the libraries.

The point is that my solution works ok for a moment but, after break times where no one uses it The solution takes a another while to load and it is because the MEF Catalog is loaded again.

I've been thinking of changing the Life time of each part to Shared so the instances will be available until my MEF Catalog is disposed.

Do you think It's good idea to make this change to my MEF Parts?

Thank you for you attention.

Ronald

Answer (score 0):

I forgot something absolutely important: the configuration of my pools.

As you remember, the default inactivity time is 20 for the pool. If the applications associated with the pool has no activity after those 20 minutes then IIS closes the working process so if I use my web apps after that time then the working process will start again (and also the initial charge of my catalog).

What I did is to set the inactivity time to zero and also configured the refreshing time of my pool (in order to clean memory at proper times).

Anyway, thank you for your attention.